# Optimize a query of an indexed table when searching for values in the indexed column that occur a lot

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table with marketing email events, where an event can be that we sent the email, and then that the recipient clicked it or opened it. Each click and open is an event. We have 2 years of data which is around 150 million rows.

I derive the email domain from each recipient email address, and I recently put an index on that domain column. This improved the performance significantly, and now I include both the domain and the address in a filter. What took 10 minutes, takes less than 10 seconds.

At least, that is true for most domains. There are 7.4 million unique email addresses, and almost half of those are GMAIL. If I query for a gmail address it is very slow, perhaps even slower than without the index. At least the top 50 most common domains take at least one minute for a basic query. The next most common domain has 400k email addresses.

Most of these are what we call "Freemail" domains and I have a long list of potential freemail and otherwise non-private domains (in addition to common email providers like gmail, it also includes "disposable" domains that users sign up for)-- this list is over 5000.

I have two questions/goals. First, would be to simply come up with a way to make querying Gmail faster (and I could selectively apply this to other most common domains). I have ideas, that may be bad, like creating a column with the first letter of the email address and making an index on that. (I am not a DBA, I had never created an index on SQL server before so don't assume I've already thought of something obvious).

The second goal would be to more generally use this for anything that is in the table of freemail domains. Most don't need it, but it ensures that whatever strategy stays up to date because that freemail table gets updated both in some automatic ways and by manually adding domains.

An example query and goal.

Goal: Summarize email engagement of a particular user over time

```
select contact_email, month_year, event_type, count(event_type) as events
from event_table
where email_domain = 'domain' and contact_email = 'email address'
group by contact_email, month_year, event_type
```

Per commenters, information on execution plans, contrasting a gmail with something uncommon. I can see they're different, do not know how to interpret.

[Gmail](https://www.screencast.com/t/Y28EAB3iLPR)

[Uncommon domain](https://www.screencast.com/t/DQuN3wgLX)

Comment: If you are filtering on the email, just create an index on `email`.

Comment: Can you explicit what is the query's goal ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff with there being so many distinct email addresses will that still be effective? I wasn't sure if there was a practical upper limit on that to actually make the index worthwhile.

Comment: @Vernou I will edit and give an example query in the post, but there's not one particular goal or query, I do similar queries (in terms of the where criteria) for various purposes.

Comment: Best would be to give us the query you are using. It may be non SARGable.
Second, check the execution plan for a fast and a slow request. Maybe the execution plan isn't the same for both queries explaining the time difference.
Next maybe create a hash column of your email address. Index this hash with the email address as included index.
When finding an email address you use the egality on the hash and on the email address. I will be faster but not a lot.

Comment: Like @Kirjava mentioned, the execution plans are one of the most important things when searching for SQL bottlenecks. Nobody will be able to help you seriously with your specific issue when there are no execution plans.

Comment: I didn't know what an execution plan was, I've added those to the post. I also don't know what SARGable. I'm generally familiar with hashes but have never done it in the context of a SQL server database. Regardless, I am looking for a significant improvement for these. Ultimately I'm building a Shiny app in R that I want to run in 30 seconds or less no matter what kind of email address the user enters; this table is the bottleneck overall the rest of the queries and R code run quickly.

Comment: Don't focus on the hash for now. It's just an improvement but won't be magic here.
SARGable means the request will use your indexes. You should always try to get SARGable requests.
On your execution plan, it is adviced to create an index. You can try that. It is an index on 2 columns (contact_email and email_domain) and it includes others columns (event_type I guess). This may improve your query.
To check it, you can type "set statistics io on" and execute it. Then you execute your request with and without this index. In the second tab, focus on the "logical reads". The less the best

Comment: I added what you should try with some explanations in the answer. I hope it will help. Please tell us if it does or if it doesn't when you will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be the index seek which is as 0% meaning it is unefficient in one case and not used in the other case.

1 - Execute

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
```

It will activate statistics for the current session. It won't persist so no need to change it to off at the end.

2 - EXECUTE your request and note what you see on your second SQL Management tab. Mostly the number of IO logical reads which are now here because of the statistics request.

3 - DROP existing indexes on this table if not used by other processes.

4 - As proposed in SQL management. You can copy past the code they propose (changing the index name)

```
CREATE NON CLUSTERED INDEX DP_LIVE_INDEX 
ON RawContactEvent(contact_email, email_domain) 
INCLUDE (event_type)
```

5 - Execute again your request and check the IO again. If it has decreased by a lot, your request is gonna be better.
Also check again the execution plan. The index seek should be on the right and be close to 100%.

**Explanation**

*Why do I focus on the logical reads instead of the execution time ?*

Logical reads are similar to the number of entries you SQL Server searched before finding the result of your select.

Usually more it has to search (many logical reads), longer the request is gonna be. If there are a lot of logical reads, that means that your indexes are not well used as an index will target the results more easily.

*Why not using the execution time ?*

Contrary to the execution time, the logical reads will same the same for a specific request if the request follows the same execution plan (which is often the case if the request isn't changed). That means that it is a really good indicator on your request performance.

*Why changing the index so few ?*

Your execution plan thinks your current index is of no use. By changing it to make it a multiple columns index or included columns, that may change the execution plan to use it better or even sometimes just to use it when it wasn't before. Making your request much more efficient.

Comment: I am doing some before/after testing right now, takes a while to run some of these and create the index.

Comment: This makes a big difference. I created the index on domain and address but didn't include event type because I want it to be more general. I'm going to accept as an answer because it addresses the specific use case that I provided. It doesn't help me with the more generalized case of when I'm only filtering on the email domain. When that becomes a practical problem I'll create a new post, and I've also learned some things that will help me too with the live query stats

Comment: I guess I'll add one more question here, which is, I can just blindly do what the query stats suggest but I assume there will be diminishing returns if I just keep creating indexes for every combination of groupings/filtering that I might do?

Comment: Indeed, creating too many indexes is reducing performance. But in your case, the index on the two columns could be used even with the request on only the domain. First, you should try changing this index by putting the email_domain first : ON RawContactEvent(email_domain, contact_email). That might make both of your requests using it because the order matters with multiple indexes (but doesn't with included indexes). 
If that doesn't work, try creating a second index and check the performance before and after that with both queries.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try those other things out as go